# Wordpress 4.4.1 Post redirect fail

Tags: wordpress, facebook, redirect

Hellou,

I have problem when i open this link (or other link) :

```
http://tesanjba.com/bih/novalic-penzije-nece-biti-smanjene-pogresno-interpretirana-izjava-drljace/
```

Redirect to :

```
http://tesanjba.com/zanimljivosti/prica-o-najstarijoj-palestinki-koja-je-odbila-ginisovu-knjigu-rekorda-zbog-hidzaba/
```

But problem is not when i crate post from my pc, only when i crate from another pc.

1. I crate post, then publish,
2. Open link, is work fine then i copy link,
3. I open my fb fan page and i Schedule post,
4. Post has published on my fan page , Description good, Header good, Image good, Link good.
5. When i open post from fb page i will be redirect to random post.

I dont have solutions, on my pc work fine(only if i create post), if i create from another pc this problem has been on both .

Sorry for my bad English i try to explain the best i can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When WordPress encounters a 404 it will try to match the "slug" (`zanimljivosti/prica-o-najstarijoj-palestinki-koja-je-odbila-ginisovu-knjigu-rekorda-zbog-hidzaba`) to the first thing it finds in the database.

Since you're having trouble on other people's machines, this suggests it's a logged-in vs. logged out issue. Check to see that your requests are coming into your server as you think they are. A simple `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` diagnosis tends to go a long way.

It seems like maybe there's a `baseurl` problem between `zanimljivosti` and `bih` (unless those are categories, in which case you're just being redirected to the first post found)